# "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I tried to enable view compilation in build time by setting this in the csproj file of my project:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

And cleaned the project.

Then an error message started to show up on build time.

> Error 10  It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  C:\projekt\FooBar\FooBar.MVC\obj\myname\package\packagetmp\web.config   38  FooBar.MVC

When clicking the error message, I am navigated to this place in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Why?

Comment: Try removing the `obj` folder and try again. If you cannot see the `obj` folder you'll need to show all hidden files.

Comment: Seems to do it! That will qualify as an answer!

Comment: I went ahead and created an answer based on my comment. Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `obj` folder and try again. If you cannot see the obj folder you'll need to show all hidden files.